# Git detects changes after new branch created and switched even though files have not been changed?

Tags: git

When I do a git revert on several files, it says they were successfully reverted they still show up as modified when I do a git status. In this case it's just a newline character at the end of the file. I also tried a reset -- hard and they files still show up! What the heck! Help please.

**UPDATE:**
In trying to reproduce this, I re-cloned the git repo from the server, which was in the exact clean state before I started last time. No files have been modified after cloning, all are identical. Then, I created a new branch (totally new, not tracking a remote branch). Viola - I now have these files show up in my git status as modified. Please note that these are files that have been tracked for several previous commits.

Just to clarify - the only command I ran to make this happen is: `git checkout -b newbranch`

And GitGui shows the files as identical even when compare whitespace is turned on.

Comment: Yes, running the latest version of mysysgit... had the same issue with an older version too so I upgraded just now and the same thing is happening.

Comment: This is usually a line endings problems. What is your autocrlf setting?

Comment: I'm aware of CRLF/LF differences between *nix and Windows... I have it set to the as-is setting. The real question is why is this not detected until I create a new branch... the files in question here have been previously committed and NOT modified.

Comment: Can you add the exact git commands you used?

Comment: Yes, `git checkout -b newbranch` That is all I did. It then detects a bunch of files that are different after the branch is created and switched. Btw - autocrlf = false

Comment: Can you insert the output of `git status file_example.ext` and `git diff` of the same file?

Comment: When I run `git status filename` it shows the file as "modified" when I run `git diff` if shows all lines as removed and all identical lines as added.